# SSh error in Whonix

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, whonix

When I try to connect to a ssh server from Whonix. This message display. Does anyone know the problem?

```
$ ssh user@193.203.202.241
uwtwrapper uwt wrapper ERROR: /usr/bin/ssh.anondist-orig does not exist.
```

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Remote_Administration

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install openssh-client
```